# Error during an upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, software-installation

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libjpeg-turbo8
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  console-setup gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly hunspell-en-us initramfs-tools
  initscripts keyboard-configuration libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libio-pty-perl liblist-moreutils-perl
  liblocale-gettext-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnetpbm10 libnih-dbus1 libnih1
  libperlio-gzip-perl libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl
  libtext-charwidth-perl libva1 mesa-common-dev netpbm python-cairo
  python-openssl python-pyorbit ttf-punjabi-fonts xdg-utils xorg
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dh-python libjpeg8
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/204 kB of archives.
After this operation, 272 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 246731 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg8:amd64 (8d-1+deb7u1) over (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.3.0-0ubuntu2
Preparing to unpack .../dh-python_1.20140511-1~bpo70+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dh-python (1.20140511-1~bpo70+1) over (1.20140128-1ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dh-python_1.20140511-1~bpo70+1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/dh_python2.1.gz', which is also in package python 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dh-python_1.20140511-1~bpo70+1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

help me master

```
sudo apt-get remove libjpeg-turbo8
sudo apt-get -f remove
sudo dpkg -r libjpeg-turbo8
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I tried to use the above commands but no effect.

Comment: Add `:amd64` to your uninstall command.

Comment: To which comment does the first code block belong?

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: try "sudo apt-get -f install"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
Unpacking libjpeg8:amd64 (8d-1+deb7u1) over (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.3.0-0ubuntu2
Preparing to unpack .../dh-python_1.20140511-1~bpo70+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dh-python (1.20140511-1~bpo70+1) over (1.20140128-1ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dh-python_1.20140511-1~bpo70+1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/dh_python2.1.gz', which is also in package python 2.7.5-5ubuntu3
```

These packages do not come from the official Ubuntu repositories and the upgrade of these packages try to overwrite files that *were* installed by another package:

```
libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
dh-python_1.20140511-1~bpo70+1_all.deb
```

You can find the source location with this commands:

```
apt-cache policy libjpeg8
apt-cache polica dh-python
```

e.g. for *Shotwell* in my installation:

```
$ apt-cache policy shotwell

shotwell:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.18.0-0ubuntu4.3
  Version table:
     0.18.0-0ubuntu4.3 0
        500 http://mirror.amsiohosting.net/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     0.18.0-0ubuntu4.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.18.0-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://mirror.amsiohosting.net/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

---

With this line:

```
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/ppa/ubuntu/ vivid/main
```

I can identify the associated list file in `/etc/apt` and/or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

e.g.:

```
$ find /etc/apt -type f | xargs grep http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yorba-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/ppa/ubuntu vivid main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yorba-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/ppa/ubuntu vivid main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yorba-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/ppa/ubuntu vivid main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yorba-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/ppa/ubuntu vivid main
```

And I would have to change or delete this file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yorba-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list
```

Remove the associated repositories and downgrade the packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8=8c-2ubuntu8
sudo apt-get install dh-python=1.20140128-1ubuntu8
```

And the upgrade will work.

Comment: libjpeg8:
      Installed: 8c-2ubuntu8
      Candidate: 8d-1+deb7u1
      Version table:
         8d-1+deb7u1 0
            500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main amd64 Packages
     *** 8c-2ubuntu8 0
            500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     

-----

dh-python:
  Installed: 1.20140128-1ubuntu8
  Candidate: 1.20140511-1~bpo70+1
  Version table:
     1.20140511-1~bpo70+1 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.20140128-1ubuntu8 0
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Remove the Kali Repositories

Comment: If you want to keep the repositories, it is more complex. One answer you will surely find [here](https://askubuntu.com/).